# Best way to create a Relational Database App in SharePoint 2010

Tags: database, access

I have a company using SharePoint 2010 wanting a SharePoint based database and UI with about 10 tables, all linked with foreign key relationships.

My preference would be to simply write a normal ASP.NET Web API App with its own database, but it must run inside SharePoint and use the SharePoint authentication and permissions system.

I thought I might be able to use an Access Web Database but then I [read this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-or-publish-a-web-database-on-SharePoint-2010-af230551-9801-495d-87b0-75eed01073ac#__toc262221095), which says these are implemented as SharePoint Lists and you can't use linked tables.

Is there some way I can write a deployable solution that will: 1) build its own tables on the SharePoint database, and 2) run JavaScript inside SharePoint web pages to access that database.

Cheers.